# how to recover data in xpad

Tags: data-recovery

I used xpad app for storing my note and it's full of my valuable notes, but the problem is xpad couldn't start for a week and it crashes! How can I recover my note fro this broken xpad ?

using terminal for running xpad I faced with this error:

```
(xpad:9488): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown tag '('

(xpad:9488): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown tag ')'

(xpad:9488): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown tag '('
```

Comment: Bug has been reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xpad/+bug/1570745

Comment: wating for bug fixing?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was just me mentioning it, so any others who were curious could follow along.  I'm sorry, I don't have an answer for you :(